# Android Checkbox appearance

Tags: android, checkbox

I am looking at the Vision Barcode example and they are using checkbox control in the xml but somehow when loaded that app on the device/emulator they appear pretty nice as you see below.

[image]

[Here is the link for the Vision Barcode Reader activity_main.xml](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)  as you see in the xml it is not a switch but do not know how it is appearing like a switch, which is a mystery!  This is how the project look in Android Studio...
[image]

Unfortunately, when I do the same thing in our company app, they appear as legacy check boxes.  That said, is there a way to force at run time to make it look like what I see in this picture, below?

When I look at the documentation for material design I do not see these in there but the legacy [one like this one](http://www.materialdoc.com/check-box/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a switch you learned not a checkbox.Check [switch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html)

Comment: No my friend, here is the xml they used https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml and it is clearly a checkbox...

Comment: forgot to thank you for the response anyway and appreciate it.

Comment: @Vincy Ther are two activity_mail.xml . One is in layout-v17. layout-v17 xml are used on devices with api level 17+ and layout xml on api's below 17. The xml in layout-v17 uses switch and that is what is displayed.

Comment: bummer, should have opened the other xml too.. my apologies!  thanks for pointing that out!  I have already changed it to switch in my case and looks great!  Did not know you could do that!  Now I know...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.android_examples.materialswitch_android_examplescom.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in your res/styles.xml:

```
 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SwitchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="colorControlActivated">#009688</item>


        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#1DE9B6</item>


        <item name="android:colorForeground">#B2DFDB</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

also make sure you add this in dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response but it is not the solution I was looking for unfortunately.  I have modified my original post and in the original code they are not using the switchcompat but checkbox.  However it appears like the switch somehow and do not know how.  May be a Android bug?  but looks pretty IMO.